# Vue 3 routing works wrong

Tags: vue.js, routes, vuejs3, vue-router

I have a menu on my project that rendered with v-for loop and dynamically shows up menu items and routes to appropriate View page. So when I click on menu item it routes to correct rout but this view page just renders on existing page. How can I fix it?

Here you can see the code in my `<HomeView/>` component.

```
<template>
  <main class="text-white relative">
    <AppHeader/>
    <SliderAppSection/>
    <AppAboutUsHome/>
    <InteriorPhoto/>
    <ProjectTypeSection/>
    <AppTestimonials/>
    <AppFooter/>
  </main>
</template>
```

The `<MobileMenu/>` component

```
<template>
  <router-link
    v-for="rout in pagesRoutes"
    :to="{name: rout.name}"
    :key="rout.name"
  >
    <button
      class="uppercase"
      :class="$store.commit('classes')"
    >
      <span></span>
      <span></span>
      <span></span>
      <span></span>
      {{ rout.name }}
    </button>
  </router-link>
</template>

<script>
import { pagesRoutes } from '../router/pagesRoutes.js';

export default {
  data() {
    return {
      pagesRoutes: pagesRoutes,
    };
  },
};
</script>
```

And here pagesRoutes

```
export const pagesRoutes = [
  {
    path: '/projects',
    name: 'projects',
    component: ProjectsView,
    children: [
      {
        path: 'interior-design',
        name: 'interiorDesign',
        component: InteriorDesignView
      },
      {
        path: 'exterior-design',
        name: 'exteriorDesign',
        component: ArchitectureView
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    path: '/services',
    name: 'services',
    component: ServicesView
  },
  {
    path: '/about_us',
    name: 'aboutUs',
    component: AboutUsView
  },
  {
    path: '/join_us',
    name: 'joinUs',
    component: JoinUsView
  },
  {
    path: '/contact_us',
    name: 'contact',
    component: ContactUsView
  }
]
```

routes/index.js

```
       let homeRouter = [
  {
    path: '/',
    name: "home",
    component: HomeView
  }
]


const router = createRouter({
  history: createWebHistory(import.meta.env.BASE_URL),
  routes: [homeRouter, ...pagesRoutes]
})
```

Comment: You aren't using this component anywhere in your templates: `<router-view></router-view>`

Comment: If that's the case, then it looks to me like no matter what link you press, `<HomeView/>` is the thing being rendered.

Comment: take a look in MenuItems component please

Comment: `<router-view />` is a placeholder component.  It will be replaced by whatever component is associated with the current route.  Placing it in the menu is _not_ where you want it to be.  You can see when the window size a bit bigger and the menu is shown along the top of the screen that the route components are rendering on the right-hand side of the menu. Put `<router-view />` where you want your actual content to appear

Comment: @DavidGyulinyan you've put route-view inside your Header nav bar. That's exactly where that content is appearing. When I click 'services', it adds the 'services' content directly into your Header nav bar, exactly where `<router-view>` is defined. As yoduh says, you want to put your `<router-view>` component in a place where you want the content-switch to happen.

Comment: @DavidGyulinyan most of the structure you have in `Home` you should actually have in `<App>`. Your root structure should be something like `<header> <router-view> <footer>` - that way, when you click a link in header, your router-view switches to whatever component that link is hooked up to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of having your `<router-view>` in your navigation header, and having your header and footer in your `Home` vue file, the structure should have your App file like this:

```
<template>
  <main class="text-white relative">
    <AppHeader/>
    <router-view />
    <AppFooter/>
  </main>
</template>

<script setup>
import { useRouter } from 'vue-router';
import AppFooter from '@/components/AppFooter.vue'
import AppHeader from '@/components/AppHeader.vue'
</script>
```

That way, whenever the url is changed by someone clicking a link in your AppHeader, the `<router-view>` changes to the component you've defined in your `router/index.js` file

In addition, there's a mistake in your router file, it should be like this:

```
const router = createRouter({
  history: createWebHistory(import.meta.env.BASE_URL),
  routes: [...homeRouter, ...mainRouter]
})
```

You had it like this:

```
routes: [homeRouter, ...mainRouter]
```

But you've defined `homeRouter` as an array, so you have to expand the array the same way you did with `mainRouter`, with `...`.